# Find all sylow subgroups of$ D_{2p^k}$, where p is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have that if $p\neq 2$, then we have Sylow p and Sylow 2 subgroups only. But what if $p=2$?

Comment: If $p=2$, then $D_{2p^k}$ is a $2$-group, meaning that it has only a Sylow $2$-subgroup equal to itself.